# Drupal with Amazon Web Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, web-applications, hosting, cloudways

I'm not sure if this is the write place to ask, but this is the only site I know where I get my questions answered... anyways

I wanted to install drupal but where should I host it? Can amazon web service host this such application? Do I need to go somewhere else and host it? I do have an account with inmotionhosting, but I was thinking if Amazon does the job, why not just use it? Any thoughts and opinions?

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for such a question but you might try here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ whether you post here or there however your questions should be precise and to the point.  Not open ended "whats your opinion?" type questions.  That being said I have all my sites hosted with hostgator and thy're awesome and they support drupal

Comment: @BenGlasser Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future drupal questions

Comment: [related](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/3729/20140)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon Web Services (AWS) will host Drupal no problem.

The service you're looking for is [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). It's pretty much equivalent to a private server with which you can do almost whatever you want (Web hosting included). The downside is that you have to do all the setup yourself.

If you don't know how to install Apache or configure your own Linux machine, you'd probably be better off with managed hosting where they'll set everything up for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can install Drupal on AWS EC2 if you have sys admin experience. Otherwise you will need to use a managed platform, like Cloudways, for that. Configuring web server like Apache and Nginx, cache like Varnish and Memcached and other features on AWS is little difficult. Many managed servers have those features available in their platform so you don't have to configure anything or go through long process of installing application on AWS.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just use AWS Cloudformation to set up your drupal environment. It's a service that is part of AWS that will set up your stack for you. you may still need to know how to handle your config files but at least you do not have to go into installing the DB , Apache etc all manually. 
http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/

Answer (score 3):

Bitnami provides a free (Apache-licensed) pre-built [Drupal image for AWS](http://bitnami.com/stack/drupal/cloud) that you launch easily. It is great for quickly testing something but if you choose the right instance for your expected load, also for production (disclaimer: I am a cofounder of Bitnami, though as I mentioned the image is open source)

Answer (score 2):

Drupal can be deployed and hosted [automatically on Jelastic PaaS](https://jelastic.com/install-application/?manifest=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fjelastic-jps%2Fdrupal%2Fraw%2Fmaster%2Fmanifest.jps). You won't need to configure it from scratch. And if you wish to make some custom settings while installation, you can also easily install it manually. Both variants are described in [the guide](https://jelastic.com/blog/how-to-install-drupal-cms-to-the-cloud/).

As a result, you'll get automatic scaling, pay-per-use pricing, management via intuitive UI, a wide choice of local service providers from different countries and other options to run your Drupal effectively.